# Failing to access account in an ATM program

Tags: c++

```
bool accessaccount(int input) {

   string temp;
   int temp2;

   ifstream notmyfile ("Accounts.txt");

   do {
      notmyfile >> temp2;

      if (temp2 == input) {
         Accno = temp2;

         notmyfile >> PIN;
         cout << "Enter PIN: "; cin >> temp2;

         if (PIN == temp2) {
            notmyfile   >> Amount   >> Fname    >> Lname;
         }  
         else return false;
      }
      else
      {
         for (int a=0; a<4; a++)
            notmyfile >> temp;
      }
   } while (!notmyfile.eof());
}
```

This is the code to access the account info from a text file. The problem is that if we somehow input the wrong ID (which is not in the text file), it lets the account number be that wrong input and the other variables are filled with garbage value. It messes up the whole ATM program. Can someone correct the error? I want the function to return false if the account is not present in the file.

Comment: Please edit this and add a Tag that identifies the language you are using.

Comment: Also, this isn't related to OOP. Fixed the tags.

Comment: How is the file delimited between records? How is the file delimited between fields? What are the expected ranges of fields? These are important things to know when parsing a file.

Comment: `temp` and `temp2` do not tell anyone anything about what the variable is *supposed* to hold.